# if statement refresh javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, events

I have made a variable called total and an if statement that check if total is above or equal to 10 then it write some text but the if statement is not refreshing when I am changing variable total somebody told me I need to use events in that case but I didn't know how

```js
var price = 5;

var quantity = 0;

var ldiscountrate = 0.05;

var hdiscountrate = 0.1;

var total = 0;

var oldtotal = price * quantity;

if (oldtotal >= 10) {
    discounttotal = total * ldiscountrate;
    document.write("you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + "total after discount " + total);
}

else if (oldtotal >= 15) {
    total = oldtotal * hdiscountrate;
    document.write("you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + "total after discount " + total);
}

else {

     total = oldtotal
    document.write("you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="var quantity+1">Add one item</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="var quantity-1">Remove one item</button>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already *are* using events. I suggest you to use functions though.

Comment: `var quantity+1` is a syntax error

Comment: Your code will only run once unless you tell it otherwise. Have you learned about [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) yet? You may also want to check the console in your developer tools for errors because your code is producing some. [freeCodeCamp](https://freecodecamp.com) is a great learning resource.

Comment: A statement (including if statements) needs to be *executed*. It doesn't automatically execute when a variable that is used somewhere changes. You need to re-execute it after you executed the assignment to `quantity`. I suggest putting it in a function so that you can easily call it and have not to repeat the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a function and call that on `onclick` event of buttons with the update values. Something like this:

```js
var price = 5;

var quantity = 0;

var ldiscountrate = 0.05;

var hdiscountrate = 0.1;

var total = 0;

var oldtotal = price * quantity;


function updateQuantity(increasedQuantity){
   quantity = increasedQuantity;
   ldiscountrate = 0.05;
   hdiscountrate = 0.1;
   total = 0;
   oldtotal = price * quantity;

  if (oldtotal >= 10) {
      discounttotal = total * ldiscountrate;
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + "total after discount " + total;
  }

  else if (oldtotal >= 15) {
      total = oldtotal * hdiscountrate;
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + "total after discount " + total;
  }

  else {

       total = oldtotal;
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$";

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(quantity+1)">Add one item</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(quantity-1)">Remove one item</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not sure how you want to display it, but `document.write` isn't working out very well, you must change that.

Comment: in your code the buttons are despairing after you press one of them

Comment: that was because of `document.write()` that you were using, i have fixed it now, check.

Comment: @AhmedYasir, check the answer, consider accepting if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, don't forget to include jquery library.
You can change your calculation as needed,
I have done as I understood.

```
<div >
    <button type="button" onclick="changequantity('add');">Add one item</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="changequantity('remove');">Remove one item</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="quantity" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="total" value="0">
</div>

<script>
function changequantity(dothis){
    var price = 5;
    var ldiscountrate = 0.05;
    var hdiscountrate = 0.1;
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
    var total = $('#total').val();
    if(dothis=="add"){
        quantity++;
    }
    if(dothis=="remove"){
        quantity--;
    }

    var oldtotal = price * quantity;

    if (oldtotal >= 10) {
        total = oldtotal - (oldtotal * ldiscountrate);
        console.log("you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + " total after discount " + total);
    }else if (oldtotal >= 15) {
        total = oldtotal * hdiscountrate;
        console.log("you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + " total after discount " + total);
    }else{
         total = oldtotal;
        console.log("you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$");
    }
    $('#quantity').val(quantity);
    $('#total').val(total);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, instead of looking for your `quantity` variable in the button's `onclick` handler, you must reference a function. The reason for this is that `onclick` expects a function, also known as an event handler or an event callback.

We can create a `addItem()` function that increases `quantity` and another `removeItem()` one that decreases it. Then, we can have each function call `updateQuantity` to have everything up to date. Remember that we should try to keep our functions lean and follow the single responsibility principle. So your code could look like this (I've replaced the `document.write` with `console.log` for clarity's sake and will explain how to improve that further down):

```
var price = 5;
var quantity = 0;
var lDiscountRate = 0.05;
var hDiscountRate = 0.1;
var total = 0;

function updateQuantity(){
    var oldTotal = price * quantity;
    var discountTotal = total * lDiscountRate;

    if (oldTotal >= 10) {
        console.log("you have a discount total was " + oldTotal + " total after discount " + total);
    } else if (oldTotal >= 15) {
        total = oldTotal * hDiscountRate;
        console.log("you have a discount total was " + oldTotal + " total after discount " + total);
    } else {
        total = oldTotal;
        console.log("you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$");
    }
}

function addItem() {
    quantity++;
    updateQuantity();
}

function removeItem() {
    quantity--;
    updateQuantity();
}
```

Here we have done a couple of important things. First of, we moved your processing logic into its own `updateQuantity` function, which will run every time you add or remove an item. This ensures that the data will keep on "refreshing" like you described. Another important bit was moving `oldTotal` inside the function so that it gets updated on each call. I also declare `discountTotal` which you did not declare and are not using in your code.

Now we only have to tie our handler functions `addItem` and `removeItem` to the DOM (your buttons). We can pass the reference to the functions to the `onclick` handler, or we can use an event listener, which is a better practice. An event listener will listen for a prescribed event (in this case `'click'` and then execute a function when that happens. What we need for this is to add `id`  to each button and then look for them in our code. We will use `document.querySelector()` to find each button and store that in a variable, and then use the `addEventListener` method that all html elements have to add the listener.

Lastly, I'll also add an empty  `<div>` where will print our messages. Note, we should avoid using `document.write` and instead write into an html element. To do this we also use `document.querySelector()` to find the element where we want to display the results, and then add your string to the `innerHTML` property.

```
var messageDiv = document.querySelector('#results');

var price = 5;
var quantity = 0;
var lDiscountRate = 0.05;
var hDiscountRate = 0.1;
var total = 0;

function updateQuantity(){
    var oldTotal = price * quantity;

    if (oldTotal >= 10) {
        var discountTotal = total * lDiscountRate;

        messageDiv.innerHTML = "you have a discount total was " + oldTotal + " total after discount " + total;
    } else if (oldTotal >= 15) {
        total = oldTotal * hDiscountRate;
        messageDiv.innerHTML = "you have a discount total was " + oldTotal + " total after discount " + total;
    } else {
        total = oldTotal;
        messageDiv.innerHTML = "you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$";
    }
}

function addItem () {
    quantity++;
    updateQuantity();
}

function removeItem () {
    quantity--;
    updateQuantity();
}

var addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton');
var removeButton = document.querySelector('#removeButton');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    addItem();
});

removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
   removeItem();
});
```

Lastly, we update your HTML bit to include the `id` for each button and the `div` to print our results. Note how we no longer need to use the `onclick` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <button type="button" id="addButton">Add one item</button>
        <button type="button" id="removeButton">Remove one item</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a working example for you: http://jsbin.com/rejutudese/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared the 'quantity' variable in the external JavaScript file, so you don't need to declare it again.  As stated by others, create a function in the JavaScript file and call it with a parameter.  Here is a sample (note that I use a div element to display the result):

(External JS file)

```
var price = 5;
var quantity = 0;
var ldiscountrate = 0.05;
var hdiscountrate = 0.1;
var total = 0;
var oldtotal = 0;

function recalculate(diff)
{
    var resultElem = null;

    try
    {
        if(quantity==0 && diff<=0)
        {
            //Ignore
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            resultElem =  document.getElementById("theResult");

            quantity+=diff;
            oldtotal = price * quantity;

            if (oldtotal >= 10) 
            {
                    discounttotal = total * ldiscountrate;
                resultElem.innerHTML="you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + " total after discount " + total;
            }
            else if (oldtotal >= 15) 
            {
                    total = oldtotal * hdiscountrate;
                resultElem.innerHTML="you have a discount total was " + oldtotal + " total after discount " + total;
            }
            else 
            {
                total = oldtotal;
                resultElem.innerHTML="you don't have a discount the total is " + total + "$";
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("recalculate Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return;
}
```

(HTML file)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Answer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="recalculate(1)" >Add one item</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="recalculate(-1)" >Remove one item</button>
    <hr/>
    <div id="theResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```